# How to make a diagonal css gradient without the colors blending together(a sharp color change) that's displaced 70% to the right?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients, gradientstop

I can't find any css gradient color generators that do what i'm trying to do.
A diagonal gradient with no blending, just a sharp color change from `#252525` to `#0099ff`(for example), with the line where the two colors meet being about 70% from the left of the container, so the line would start a little more than halfway across the x axis of the container, and the line would end maybe halfway down the y axis of the right side of the container.

If you would be able to emphasize what numbers are specifically for calculating the degree of tilt, and the x y coordinates of the beginning of the gradient, that would be so extremely helpful. I'm just confused at this point.